# Parse error in PHP (t_string)

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am getting error in following code.  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'size' (T_STRING) in line 7. Please help

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
function fontWrap( $txt, $size ) {
print “<font size=\”$size\”
face=\”Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif\”>
$txt</font>”;
}
fontWrap(“A heading<br>”,5);
fontWrap(“some body text<br>”,3);
fontWrap(“some more body text<BR>”,3);
fontWrap(“yet more body text<BR>”,3);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting of any good (probably even the majority of bad text editors) would show you the problem pretty quickly. Whatever you're using, get rid of it and start using [something](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) [better](http://www.sublimetext.com/)

Answer (score 5):

You're using funky quotes. Change `“` and `”` to `"`.

And stop using MS Word as a text editor. :)

Comment: I laughed at the MS Word part! Nice catch though. :)

Comment: smart quotes are anything but when dealing with code. I call them "moron quotes" at this point.

Comment: Curly quotes; *beautiful, yet deadly*. Just like Mata Hari ;)

Answer (score 0):

NM: looks like the quotes was the problem. Not the lack of parentheses.

```
print("<font size='$size' face='Helvetica,Arial,Sans-Serif'>$txt</font>");
```

Although, you might want to use CSS and span tags and make a function to insert the tag for this by defining a CSS style sheet that defines standard font-family and sizes so your presentation is separate from your content, and more consistent (note: most typography uses different sizes sparingly — 1 each for head, subhead, body and caption usually) as well as making changes easier. (If you change the size smaller or larger then each function call in the script will have to be searched for and replaced with new values, assuming it is present in multiple places).
In the css:

```
body{
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
.heading {
    font-size: 2em;
}
.normal {
    font-size: 1em;
}
.note {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: .5em;
}
.subhead {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Later in the php class or global functions:

```
public function spanClass($copy,$class){
    print("<span class='$class'>$copy</span>");
}
```

In the php webpage itself:

```
spanClass("Cool Things","heading");
…
spanClass("& Other Stuff","subhead");
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print.php